# How can I hide the NTUSER.dat file?

Tags: windows-10

I have read a few other answers here. All I'd like to know is whether there's a way to hid the NTUSER.dat file while still viewing other hidden files in my %USERPROFILE% directory.

This is for no other reason than the fact that it is ugly.

Comment: Don’t show system files

Comment: @Appleoddity how do I do this?

Comment: It is a check box in the same interface where you told windows to show hidden files.

Comment: @EBGreen I see three check boxes: Item Check Boxes, File Name Extensions, and Hidden Items. ?

Comment: Aaah...I forgot that they changed that. Click the View tab then Options -> Change folder and search options. In there click the View tab and check 'Hide protected operating system files'

Comment: @EBGreen As it turns out, I already had that checked. Even so, NTUSER.DAT appears.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked. ntuser.dat doesn't appear to be flagged as system. Personally, I think this should be expected if you're going to always show hidden files. But you can certainly go in and set the system attribute on those files, so that they are hidden using the `attrib +s <filename>` command. Make sure you are actually in your profile directory first. Other than that, it's just the way it is. There shouldn't be any need to have hidden files shown on a day to day basis.

Comment: Yeah, if you choose to show hidden files seeing them is kind of on you.